# How to read non-acroform PDF form fields with iTextG?

Tags: android, forms, pdf, itext

I am trying to populate a PDF template with a family tree.  The root node is the descendent, and it branches out into each pair of ancestors.

I am using PDF stamper to populate the form that goes back 3 generations.

[image]

I have created the above form in Open Office 4.1.1.  I added Label Fields using the Form Design Mode and exported to PDF with "Create Forms" checked and using PDF format (also tried FDF).

The following is my iTextG integration:

```
            reader = new PdfReader( src );

            stamper = new PdfStamper( reader, baos );
            stamper.setFormFlattening( true );

            form = stamper.getAcroFields();
            xfa = form.getXfa();

            Log.i("FamilyTreeStorage Form Type", ( xfa.isXfaPresent() )? "XFA Form":"AcroForm" );

            Set<String> fields = form.getFields().keySet();
            if ( !fields.isEmpty() ){
                for( String key : fields ){
                    Log.i("FamilyTreeStorage", String.format("key= %s; type= %d;", key, form.getFieldType( key )) );
                }
            }else{
                Log.i("FamilyTreeStorage", "AcroFields returned empty set.");
            }
```

The thing is that the form.getFields() does read form fields properly in PDF docs that I have gotten from other sources that contain AcroForms. The PDF that I generated with Open Office only returns an empty set for acro fields.  It thinks there is no acro form.  How do I populate non-acro form forms with iTextG?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Indeed: without seeing the PDF, we can not answer this question as we can create PDF forms using open office without any problem.

Comment: I had success creating the same PDF with Acrobat Pro.  Maybe the real question is how to get Open Office to contain Acro Forms. How do I add the PDF to this post?

Comment: Upload it to a site that's accessible to the public. You could use Dropbox' public folder for this.